# PySpark jdbc errors with Method setProperty error

Tags: python, oracle, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am facing the below error when writing data into the oracle database . I am facing below weird error.

I am not sure what's the issue is below is the code

```
 self.batchsize = 50000
 self.tgt_url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@' + self.tgt_hostname + ":" + self.tgt_port + "/" + self.tgt_schema
 self.tgt_connectionProperties = {"user": self.tgt_username, "password": self.tgt_password,"driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "batchszie": self.batchsize}
 temp_table = self.TgtDatabase + "." + self.TgtTable
 self.inmemdf.write.jdbc(self.tgt_url, table = temp_table , mode='append', properties=self.tgt_connectionProperties)

    An error occurred while calling o171.setProperty. Trace:
    py4j.Py4JException: Method setProperty([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I initially thought it was data issue and even casted the data to the target datatype as well. Unable to understand what type of error is this

Comment: if we change the code ti below it is working self.inmemdf.write.format('jdbc').options(url=self.tgt_url,driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", dbtable=temp_table,user=self.tgt_username,password=self.tgt_password,batchsize=self.batchsize).mode("overwrite").option("truncate","true").save()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you have a typo in your code `"batchszie": self.batchsize`, it should be `"batchsize": self.batchsize`
2. `self.batchsize` is of type Integer, while the error says that there is no method for (String, Integer), so just change it to String:

```
self.batchsize = '50000'
```